# Pegar corretamente qual div foi clicada

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho algumas divs:

```
<div class="filter__filters tamanho"></div>
<div class="filter__filters preco"></div>
<div class="filter__filters cor"></div>
```

Estou tentando pegar qual foi clicado, assim:

```
$j('.filters__filter').click(function(){
    $j(this).click();
});
```

Só que fica dando erro de tamanho: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Eu queria que toda vez que eu clicasse ne uma dessas divs, eu pegasse qual foi clicado. Como faço isso corretamente? Ou melhor, por que está dando esse erro?

Comment: $('.filters__filter').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta quase certo, mas o problema esta no click de dentro, você clica e depois chama o evento click de novo dentro:

```
$j('.filter__filters').click(function(){
    $j(this).click();
});
```

Você tem que definir o que você quer fazer, por exemplo, vamos supor que você queira pega o texto então:

```
$j('.filter__filters').click(function(){
    alert($j(this).text());
});
```

Assim você vai pegar o texto da div que foi clicada.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, erro de lógica rsrs. Quando der o tempo marco como aceita!

Comment: Vc tem outro erro ainda atenção ao nome da classe no HTML e no jQuery, está escrito de forma diferente

Comment: @HelderPereira, verdade eu não tinha reparado nisto, realmente a classe deve ter o mesmo nome na tag e no jquery "filter__filters".

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você está no caminho, a questão é que você está tentando simular novamente o `click` na mesma `div` clicada anteriormente.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.filter__filters', function(){
  $('.filter__filters').css('background', 'white')
  $(this).css('background', 'red')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter__filters tamanho">a</div>
<div class="filter__filters preco">b</div>
<div class="filter__filters cor">c</div>
```